# How to add this html in a div, escaping the quotes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some html code that i want to add dynamically to a div in a page.

My div is:

```
<div id="my_div" class="my_class">
</div>
```

This is my html code that i want to add to the above div, when i click on some button, using jquery onclick event.

```
<div id="content">
'Hello world 123' <br>
<img src='player.gif' width='200' height='100'>
Good morning...
Have a nice day...
</div>
```

So far, i tried this general way, when onclick event is invoked:

```
document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML = 
'<div id="content">
    'Hello world 123' <br>
    <img src='player.gif' width='200' height='100'>
    Good morning...
    Have a nice day...
    </div>';
```

But as you can see, the code is error prone, as the quotes are mismatched and it breaks. How can i escape the quotes and add the content to div efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should do the job:

```
document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML = 
"<div id=\"content\">
    'Hello world 123' <br>
    <img src='player.gif' width='200' height='100'>
    Good morning...
    Have a nice day...
 </div>";
```

Instead i have escaped the double quotes around content.

Comment: Just a small issue though... i am not able to add the <script></script> tags inside my dynamic div content. It is not accepting. But i need to add it there. How can i escape those tags?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use backslash to escape it:

```
document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML = 
'<div id="content">
    \'Hello world 123\' <br>
    <img src=\'player.gif\' width=\'200\' height=\'100\'>
    Good morning...
    Have a nice day...
    </div>';
```

Comment: The escape function is NOT appropriate for this use.  You'd still have to get the whole contents into a Javascript string before you could call escape() anyway and escape() doesn't help you at all with the quote character issue or produce readable HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML = 
'<div id="content">
    \'Hello world 123\' <br>
    <img src="player.gif" width="200" height="100">
    Good morning...
    Have a nice day...
    </div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

With a simple example

http://jsfiddle.net/arjunshetty2020/MPYXS/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
       document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML ="<p id=\"test\">\"test1\" <br/>    test2<p>" ;
    });
});
```